# Custom Metadata deployment through MDAPI

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, custom-metadata

I have been trying to deploy a package through SFDX (sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml ..).
My package contains custom Metadata to be deployed.I have made sure that they are in my package and also in package.xml. But when I deploy the package, I get an error:

Custom metadata type Marketing_Cloud_Config__mdt is not available in this organization.

Do I need to first deploy custom metadata and then deploy the rest?
Attaching the screenshots.[image: Deployment Error]

[image: VSCODE package.xml]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need the Custom Metadata types themselves, which are exposed as CustomObject entries:

```
<types>
  <members>Archived_email_search_configuration__mdt</members>
  <members>Marketing_Cloud_Config__mdt</members>
  <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Note the use of `__mdt` instead of the "usual" `__c` suffix.

Both the CustomObject entries and CustomMetadata entries may be deployed at once in the same package.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox that works!!